# If $\lim_n(x_{n+1}-x_n)=4$, can the sequence $\{\sin(x_n)\}$ be convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)=4$, is it possible that the sequence $(\sin(x_n))$ can be convergent or does it have to be divergent?
The reason why I asked this is because if $0<\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)<\pi$, then $(\sin(x_n))$ has to be divergent as we can find two subsequences of it such that one is a positive sequence and the other one is a negative sequence. However, if it is $4$ then we are not able to find such two subsequences. That's why I wonder what the answer is to this question.

Comment: It has to be divergent

Comment: It is tempting to think that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)=4$, then $|x_n-y_n|\to0$ if we choose $y_n=a+4n$ for a suitable $a\in\mathbb R$. If it were so, we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(y_n)$ (one exists if and only if the other one does) and we could do a more explicit computation. But this is not true, as the example sequence $x_n=4n+\log(5+n)$ shows.

Comment: While I think it is true to conclude $x_n=4n+o(n)$ though.

Comment: Is my answer with Arcsinus correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose that $(\sin(x_n))$ is convergent to a limit $l \in \mathbb{R}$. Then you have
$$\sin(x_{n+1})=\sin(x_{n+1}-x_n + x_n)=\sin(x_{n+1}-x_n)\cos(x_n) + \cos(x_{n+1}-x_n)\sin(x_n) \quad \quad (1)$$

$$\sin(x_{n-1})=\sin(x_n - (x_n - x_{n-1}))=\sin(x_n)\cos(x_n-x_{n-1}) - \cos(x_n)\sin(x_n-x_{n-1}) \quad (2)$$

Let $n \rightarrow +\infty$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$ : you get that $(\cos(x_n))$ converges to a limit $l'$ satisfying
$$l=\sin(4)l'+\cos(4)l \quad \quad (1')$$
$$l = l \cos(4) - l'\sin(4) \quad \quad (2')$$

If you sum $(1')$ and $(2')$, you get
$$2l = 2l \cos(4)$$

so $$l=0$$

and $(1')$ gives then $l'=0$, which contradicts the fact that $l^2 + l'^2 = 1$ (by letting $n \rightarrow +\infty$ in $\cos^2(x_n) + \sin^2(x_n)=1$)